# SSH public keys not working

Tags: ssh, centos, openssh

I've spent a few hours trying to solve this, but have gotten nowhere.

The server is running CentOS 6 and using OpenSSH. The client is running OpenSSH too.

I created a public key on the client (my PC) using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and then sent it to the server using `ssh-copy-id user@host`.

After, I logged onto the server (using password) and saw the file was there and has some stuff in it. I changed its permissions to 600 [as stated on the CentOS Wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH).

I then tried to SSH into the server again, but I had to enter a password. Here's the output using the verbose option:

```
user@hostname ~ $ ssh censored@censored -v
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to censored [censored] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 92:67:19:72:5f:ed:b1:a3:14:7f:f3:82:e2:4d:ef:16
debug1: Host 'censored' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
censored@censored's password:
```

In the server's SSHD configuration I have uncommented and modified a couple of options like so:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile /home/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I have also tried running `ssh-add` on the server, but when I do `ssh-add -l`, none show up.

Any help would be really appreciated.

edit: the problem may be client side. I tried to set this up with my Raspberry Pi and get this when connecting too:

```
user@hostname ~ $ ssh pi@raspberrypi -v
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to raspberrypi [192.168.1.70] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 72:e3:36:15:72:c9:ca:9f:66:a9:d5:3f:88:d0:7a:e7
debug1: Host 'raspberrypi' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pi@raspberrypi's password:
```

Answer (score 2):

Or just:

```
restorecon -R -v /root/.ssh
```

Answer (score 1):

In the steps listed, I don't see anything that suggests you added the public key to the `authorized_keys` files.

On the server, try:

```
cat /path/to/key.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys{,2}
```

Shell expansion should do both files hopefully.

Locally, you may need to include an `~/.ssh/config` file which would be permissions of 600. If you think you need it I'll post mine as an example. In it you can specify usernames and easier hostnames to use (rather than `user@example` it would just be ssh chosenname)

Also, is your local key in `~/.ssh`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used `ssh-copy-id` which appeared to work because before there was no authorized_keys file, yet after there way. I tried `cat` earlier after copying the key with `scp`, but I got the same results.

Comment: @Matthew - do you have both `authorized_keys` and `authorized_keys2`? Does your `sshd_config` file allow or deny any protocol (1/2)?bsinve making edits, have you restarted the service?

Comment: No, there's only `authorized_keys`. In `sshd_config` I see `Protocol 2` the stuff above is commented out.

edit: yeah, I've done "sudo service sshd restart" after each modification of the config.

Comment: I'd try `cat /path/to/publickey.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2` (whatever path you added for sshd to use). I'd probably comment out the custom path in sshd until you get it working. But I've never messed with that option before.

Comment: I tried that after `scp`ing the id_key.pub, but it still doesn't work. :S

Comment: I also just tried deleting all keys on my computer, creating a new one then `scp`ing it to the server, deleted existing authorized_key* on the server and then used `cat` again, same problem.

Comment: I think the problem is client side. I updated my post.