# Can't login via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

I generated public and private keys, with the help of `ssh-keygen`.

Now I want to add `public_key` to the server, to add `public_key` into server first I want to login into the server but I am not able to login into the server getting error `permission denied(publickey,password)`.

How can I login into the server and how to copy the `public_key` contents into the server side `authorized_key` file.

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Port 22, 
Protocol 2,
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key 
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval yes
ServerKeyBits 768
SyslogFacility AUTH
Loglevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubketAuthentication yes
HostbasedAuthentication no
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
```

Contents of `/var/log/auth.log`:

[image: ssh-copy-id]

Contents of `/etc/passwd`:

[image: /etc/passwd file]

Contents of `auth.log`:

[image: auth.log]

Attempts to run`ssh -vv debian@192.168.7.2`:

[image: ssh -vv debian@192.168.7.2]

Contents of the `/.ssh/config file`:

[image: /.ssh/config file]

The SSH status:

[image: SSH status:]

Checking firewall running status:

[image: Checking firewall running status:]

[login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er51W.png)

[ssh-copy-id]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH public keys not working](https://superuser.com/questions/542276/ssh-public-keys-not-working)

Comment: What are the permissions on `~/.ssh/` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`? They should be 0600 and 0700 respectively. You can check with `ls -l ~/.ssh`

Comment: @TimeSheep This is 100% correct. The commands to run are `chmod 700 ~/.ssh/` and `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. And also make sure your user is the owner of those files by running this command: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.ssh/`

Comment: yes the permissions are 700 for .ssh and 600 for authorized_keys only,

Answer (score 0):

Your `debian` user has no shell set.

Set the shell via:

```
$ sudo chsh -s /bin/bash debian
```

Comment: after sudo chsh -s /bin/bash debian command I get the  debian user shell after this I am trying but facing same issue..next how to proceed..sir

Comment: Check the `auth.log`, and run `ssh -vv debian@…` from the client to get more information.

Comment: I checked the auth.log file and shown on above question please go throw it, and when I run the ssh -vv debian@192.168.7.2 I am getting the connection refused error that also I attched on  above question,please suggest...

Comment: hey guys,please replay me...

Comment: If the connection is refused and the server is up, check that there is not any firewall running.

Comment: Thankyou for the replay,I am little bit confuse either firewall is running or not, as I attached above,sudo ipatbles -L showing,but "service iptables status" showing command not fount,what is the command for checking firewall running or not..

Comment: guys replay me....please

Comment: The firewall is running but accepting all connections, according to your screenshot. It is, however, a bit weird that you are getting connection refused by adding `-vv` to your SSH command, because if you get the "Permission denied" it means that you did connect, but failed authentication.

Comment: I am login with the command "ssh debian@192.168.7.2" and I attached the result in my question,I am little bit confuse either I connected to my beaglebone or normal debian user?

Comment: @Asha Looks like you're logged in now. Do you know what you changed to make it work?

Comment: I logged in beaglebone only?,but its not showing any files...i am  in confuse

Comment: @Asha I don't know if I can help you sort out the confusion as to which computer you're logged in. You can run `ifconfig` to check the IP address and `hostname` to see the hostname. If you don't see any files, that's maybe because you're in the home folder of the newly created `debian` user.

Comment: Thankyou, is it possible wothout pluging(connecting)  beaglebone to my laptop able to login "ssh debian@192.168.7.2"?, why I am asking this question means,I am able to login "ssh debian@192.168.7.2" without pluging(connecting) beaglebone to my laptop.....

Comment: Sir...I am getting the "ssh: connect to host 192.168.7.2 port 22:Connection refused" error...not getting where I am doing the mistake...can you help me...please..

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help you, as I was under the impression that it already worked. Your network setup is not clear at all. I don't understand how you want to be able to connect to the Beaglebone if you don't connect it to the laptop or the same network. If the connection is refused, check if the SSH service is running and that there is no firewall running.

Comment: how to see the droplet IP Address?  if I create new ssh keys ,is it necessary to add those new ssh keys into droplet? if  YES then how to add those keys into the droplet?..I am new in this feild so don't have much knowledge..your suggestions are more helpful for me..

Comment: Droplets? Are you talking about DigitalOcean VMs? It may be that you are new in this field, but this is not a forum, and comments are really not suitable for troubleshooting this way. Please make sure that you explain your full situation, what your artchitecture is, what you are trying to do, etc. *in your question*. But yes, when you create new SSH keys, you have to add them to the remote server.

Comment: in my system,I have only known_hosts file, don't have any id_rsa and id_rsa.pub ,authorized_keys files ,as read some of the documents its necessary to have this files..so I want to try ,to create new ssh keys and how can I add those keys into the remote server?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine

Comment: as per that, I am trying to copy the keys but getting error,I attached that into question,1st screenshot please go through that..

Comment: I really can't, sorry. It's too confusing, there is too much information about different problems in your post. Perhaps you should delete this question and write a new one, where you concentrate on the actual issue and describing your architecture.